# VSCode Live Share, Cannot log in with GitHub, "user code" command is missing

Tags: login, visual-studio-code, github

Playing with VSCode Live Share for the first time today, I cannot get logged in with GitHub.

From VSCode, I click "Sign In with Github", and click the green Authorize VisualStudentLiveShare button. And then at the "Ready to Collaborate" screen, it asks to use xdg-open, and I click "Open xdg-open", which typically launches a native app. But then it fails with "Failed to open URI vscode://.... The specified location is not supported":

[image: Error message]

Which is odd, because the live share links work, just not the link to sign in with github.

The "Ready to Collaborate" screen offers help, suggesting I use the Command Palette and enter "user code" as shown:

[image]

...but when I do that, there are "no matching commands":

[image]

Help - how do I get logged in to VSCode Live Share with Github under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's irritating. I had an instance of VScode open in another workspace. The answer is (yet again) close *all instances* of vscode, and when you restart, the "user code" will be available in your Command Palette.

[image: After restart, user code is found]